# How do the gears relate to the speed of the car?

Tags: motorcycle, manual-transmission

I am just starting out riding a motorcycle and I am confused on the relation between the gears and the speed.

If you are cruising 45mph (72 kph) on the 4th gear and you have to come to an emergency stop since the front car randomly slams the brakes, do you simply just brake without downshifting? Since once you brake you will go down gradually from 45mph (72kph) to 0mph all in gear 4.

I am not able to understand if that is ok or not since I don't understand what gear 4 means really in relation to how fast you are going. Can someone clarify this?

Comment: Just try to brakes first and then use the clutch when the speed reduced. You can downshift once the speed reduced. Or you can stop the car without downshifting but make sure you use the clutch when the speed reduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just brake without downshifting in an emergency, then sort the gearbox out when you've managed to stop.

On a bike though you soon get very used to down changing down gears to help you slow down. However in an emergency (and assuming the road is dry) you would normally just hit the front brake as hard as is possible without locking the front wheel, pulling in the clutch just to prevent the bike stalling. However it becomes second nature to quickly change (stamp) down the gears at the same time too.

It is correct to use the rear brake as well in an emergency, but there's not much point when braking hard, as the rear of the bike will be unloaded weight wise, so it will be trying to leave the ground anyway making the rear brake useless. You can really only add rear brake when stopping in a controlled manor, & changing down gears as your speed reduces.

Don't get too hung up on what speed is right for this changing down proceedure whilst braking, as you will be using the clutch at the same time.. So even if you do go down a gear or two too many, you'd use the clutch to prevent the bike over-revving or locking the rear wheel etc (assuming no slipper clutch fitted.)

On a modern 1000cc road bike, gears 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 etc are used in relation to engine rpm and road speeds. You use whats acceptable to keep the engine within an acceptable rpm range for the speed your travelling and the road gradients/conditions etc. You wouldn't for example use 6th gear at 30mph as the rpms would be extremely low risking stalling the bike, plus it would be rather uncomfortable for the rider too as the bike would be very unhappy at such low revs.

Again on a modern 1000cc road bike, gear 4 may be used anywhere between 40 and 150mph, so as you can see the gears have a huge speed range. If travelling at say 60mph changing up or down two gears on such a bike would be fine.. On smaller bikes though changing gear would be more frequent due to having gears required for the lower weights and speeds etc.

Comment: Hello! I had a quick question. When I downshift, I first let off the throttle, press the clutch, downshift, and let go of the clutch slowly. When I do this my bike jerks a little bit. Is that because when you go to a lower gear the RPM is higher causing the engine to spin faster. So when you let go of the clutch the engine is spinning faster, so the transmission will transmit more power to the wheels so you jerk forward? I know this is a mediocre and dumb question but my physics is horrible, I am a software engineer lol...

Comment: You just have to match the engine speed, with the gearbox and road speed. Try letting the clutch out a little slower, that should smooth thingsbout untill you get used to whats going on. Don't worry.. all will become second nature soon enough. When going from neutral to 1st gear, almost all bikes snap into gear here with a bit of a clunk, its normal.

Comment: Engine speed is determined by RPM but what is gearbox speed and road speed determined by? Indirectly the RPM correct?

Comment: They are all linked together, only separated by the clutch. The gearbox speed is determined by the rear wheel speed but the different ratio gears allow for varying options for suitable synchronisation between engine rpm, gearbox and thus rear wheel speeds.